# Questions related to a newly created landmass

Tags: internal-consistency, geography, geology

As a continuation for [my previous island](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/101656/is-this-landmass-somewhat-realistic) I decided to work on it some more.
I've got something I quite like, but once more I'm overwhelmed by the questions that arise.

This is my freshly created landmass: (2 cubes = 500km It's located on an Earth-sized planet, the picture describes a reversed "C" landmass that's surrounded by ocean.)
[image]

Some of the questions that I have:

**How Geologically realistic is this landmass? Is it possible for it to exist? **

I will definitely come back with more questions, but that's all I have for now, thanks!

Comment: I'll admit to be just an enthusiast of geology, though I could recommend starting with the tectonic plates and forming the geography from that.  Where tectonic plates meet there is usually a rift (San Andreas fault line), a mountain range (the Rockies), or an ocean (Atlantic ocean).  Volcanoes can also form where a tectonic plate moves underneath another.  While you could attempt a realistic landscape and work backwards, it'd be like drawing a realistic face without understanding the bone structure underneath.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking: I see a closed figure, no other info. It could be a lake surrounded by land or an island surrounded by sea. With no graphical hints on the local topography, for example, how can we even try to answer you questions? I'll be more than happy to retract the VTC after you edit the question.

Comment: Beyond the concerns mentioned by @L.Dutch, please refrain from asking multiple questions at once. (And especially don't "come back" to add questions.)  Doing so is strongly discouraged as it complicates the answering process and often results in a question being closed as _too broad_.

Comment: Please ask one question per post at a time. You can always later come back and ask a new question in a new post where you incorporate the feedback you got on previous posts and link to the older ones. You should generally wait a bit before asking a new question so that you get some feedback on the first questions.

Comment: Without having any information on geography/tectonics, land can take almost any form. So the answer is yes but you should include more parameters to make it more like an actual question.

Comment: I believe the only viable answer to this question is "sure, why not?"  As @Vincent pointed out, we know nothing about the world.  The landmass could exist due to a meteor impact, currents erroding a soft interior soil, a sunken geography, or many other reasons - but their suitability depends on (frankly) the rest of the planet.  Honestly, it's a good looking land mass.  I'd worry less about the planetological details and roll with it.

Answer (score 2):

## Your continent is Africa

[image]

At the scale you mentioned, I measure the overall size of the continent (including the smaller sub-continent) at 6250 by 6000 km. Africa is slightly larger at 7900 by 7300 km. The sub-continent I measure at 2500 by 1500 km; this is about the same size as Morocco and Algeria, at 2500 by 1900 km.

I propose that you model your continent after Africa, which is all formed on one tectonic plate. As you see from the elevation map, it isn't too far fetched to imagine with slightly higher sea levels that the upland areas of Morocco and Algeria in the far northwest could be separated into a smaller sub-continent off the coast.

Africa has plenty of tall mountain ranges, formed by the volcanic action of the Great Rift Valley. There are volcanic mountain ranges like the Tibetsi and Cameroon line. Most of southern Africa is a high, flat plateau; the center in Congo is a sunken basin, punctuated by a mighty scar where the basin's rainforest unleashed its waters on the Atlantic.

Look up stuff on Africa, and make your continent look like that.